# A typecasting on C

Tags: c

Is typcasting in c is basically to change the sizes of the variables, or it also saves the sign of variable too?

```
int a; 
signed char b = 0xf4;
unsigned char c = 0xf4;

a = (signed int)c;
a = b;
```

here same values are given to a, but one is a typecasted value and another is a simple signed char.
    so in first case is only the size of value of c is increased

Comment: did you read the first line?

Comment: What you're doing isn't type "casting" as much as it is simple type *conversion*. The term "casting" is usually reserved for dirty pointer games (even though the grammatical term for your syntax is indeed "cast"). My point is that conversions follow a simple (though lengthy) set of rules.

Answer (score 2):

As you can hear from the name you're using, it's about changing the *type* of a value.

You can cast between integer and floating-point:

```
int x = (int) 3.14159265363;
```

or between pointer types:

```
int a = 4711, b;
void *ap = &a;
b = *(int *) ap;
```

So no, it's not about the "size". Of course the size must change if the type you're casting to demands it, but not all casts must change the size and it's definitely not all that happens. Conversion from floating point to integer is typically done with dedicated instructions, it's not just a matter of throwing bits away (or padding a value with to make it wider).

Answer (score 2):

Yes actually, it is about the size of the types.

A int is 4 bytes, so in memory, it looks like that :

```
 int a = 3;
 // looks like this
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
```

When you do this:

```
 char b = (char)a;
```

It will truncate to get the proper number of bytes, here one, so `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011` will be truncated to `00000011`

The same works for every type.
This is really important to understand typecasting, and limit overflows, and even though that's not all that is done by most compiler, that's the basics.

Comment: so it does not take sign of the variables into account, just matches the size on both sides.

Comment: @mrigendra I don't really understand what you mean. The sign of the variable only changes what the first bit is for. When you declare a variable unsigned, the first bit is not used for negation anymore. That's why you can't store negative numbers anymore but larger positive number.